# center image in div with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, center

I have an image of 400px and a div that is smaller (the width is not always 300px as in my example). I want to center the image in the div, and if there is an overflow, hide it.

Note: I must keep the `position:absolute` on the image. I'm working with css-transitions, and if I use `position:relative`, my image shakes a bit (https://web.archive.org/web/20120528225923/http://ta6.maxplus.be:8888/).

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wjw83/1/

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what exactly is the problem and what do you try to achieve. Is [that it](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/wjw83/3/) ?

Comment: on  http://bit.ly/MaYbMB, the tab 'coaching' shakes a bit if you hover it. I want to solve that using position:absolute. The problem is that overflow:hidden doesnt affect a child element with position:absolute.

Comment: I don't see any image on the archived link: maybe you could [edit] your question and remove the link entirely. Also, please insert the content of the fiddle in your question directly, thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should make the container relative and give it a height as well and you're done.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/wjw83/4/

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

img.absolute {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img class="absolute" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200/A44/EED?text=Hello" alt="" />
</div>
<br />
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200/A44/EED?text=Hello" alt="" />
```

If you want to you can also center the image vertically by adding a negative margin and top position: http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/wjw83/5/

Comment: This is old.... Man you just saved hours of debugging how to do it!! Really apreciate...

Comment: this won't work for images with different dimensions

Comment: I used for gif. thanks. :) . if you want photo is be full. use the this width: 100%, height: 100%

Answer (score 27):

None of the above solutions were working out well for me. I needed a dynamic image size to fit in a circular parent container with `overflow:hidden`

```
.circle-container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.circle-img img {
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:none;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 -100%;
}
```

Working example here:
http://codepen.io/simgooder/pen/yNmXer

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've been searching for a way to do this for a few nights now and you've solved it!

Comment: No problem! It took a lot of messing about, but it has so many applications - it's almost indispensable.

Comment: Thank you! I have been coming back to this problem over time because I've never been 100% satisfied with other solutions... `transform: translate` just being too fussy. I tried a number of times to use `margin:0 auto` which did not work. The real magic happens with `margin:0 -100%` instead of the `auto` value :)

Answer (score 26):

Most recent solution:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.jpg" height="600" width="600"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Magic */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* vertical */
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal */
}
```

Comment: Nicely proposed, simple, clean and effective. This is good CSS coding. Congrats :-)

Comment: @SamuelRamzan Thanks!

Comment: For different-sized images, I had to tweak the code by setting `justify-content: stretch;` so that the image would fill the width of the container.

Comment: Great solution! I was able to utilize `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` to only specify a set width on the parent element. Useful if you have dynamic components

Answer (score 7):

Found this nice solution by MELISSA PENTA (https://www.localwisdom.com/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
  height:200px;
  line-height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  width:200px;
}
div.wrapper img {
  margin:-100%;
}
```

**Center any size image in div** 
Used with rounded wrapper and different sized images.

CSS

```
.item-image {
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.item-image img {
    height: 200px;    
    margin: -100%;
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;    
}
```

Working example here [codepen](http://codepen.io/egle/pen/wJwzzp)

Answer (score 6):

For me flex-box worked perfect to center the image.

this is my html-code:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="..." >
</div>
```

and this i used for css:
I wanted the Image same wide as the wrapper-element, but if the height is greater than the height of the wrapper-element it should be "cropped"/not displayed.

```
.img-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

working solution with `flex-box` for posterity:

main points:

1. overflow hidden for wrapper
2. image height and width must be specified, cannot be percentage.
3. use any method you want to center the image.

```css
  wrapper {
    width: 80;
    height: 80;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  image {
    width: min-content;
    height: min-content;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .div-main{
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background:url(img.jpg) no-repeat center center
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div-main">  
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

just make sure how you are using image through css background use backgroud image position like background: url(your image path) no-repeat center center; automatically it wil align center to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work on our site, using your ideas and a little math based upon the left edge of wrapper div.  It seems redundant to go left 50% then take out 50% extra margin, but it seems to work.

```
div.ImgWrapper {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

img.CropCenter {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto !important;
    height: 160px !important;
}

<div class="ImgWrapper">
<a href="#"><img class="CropCenter" src="img.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you the have to corp your image from sides to hide it try this

[3 Easy and Fast CSS Techniques for Faux Image Cropping | Css ...](https://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/)

one of the demo for the first way on the site above

[try demo](http://cssglobe.com/lab/imagecrop/01.html)

i will do some reading on it too

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to implement Jaap's answer inside [this page](http://artune.be/?q=notes) of my recent site, with one difference : the .main {height:} was set to auto instead of a fixed px value.
As responsive developer i am looking for a solution to synchronize the image height with the left floating text element, yet only in case my text height becomes greater then my actual image height. 
In that case the image should not be rescaled, but cropped and centered as decribed in the original question here above.
Can this be done ?
You can simulate the behaviour by slowly downsizing the browser's width.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a huge pain in the a.. but I finally got it.
I've seen a lot of complicated solutions. This is so simple now that I see it.

```
.parent {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
}

.child {
  height:100%;
  width:10000px; /* Or some other impossibly large number */
  margin-left: -4965px; /* -1*((child width-parent width)/2) */
}

.child img {
  display:block; /* won't work without this */
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```