# Centering image inside a div using CSS instead of jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fit any sized image inside a (always) square div, and retain the aspect when the size of the parent div changes. Here's what I'm doing:

CSS:

```
.photo_container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.photo_container a img{
    position:absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<!--p>Photo's height>width </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="photo"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/ECurtis.jpg/224px-ECurtis.jpg" 
style="width:100%; height:auto;">
        </img>
    </a>
</div>

<!--p>Photo's width>height </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="photo"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/220px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" 
style="width:auto; height:100%;left=-100px">
        </img>
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// fix image size on load
$(".photo").one("load", function() {
  fixImage($(this));
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});

// Just to test if everything's working fine
$(".photo").on("click",function(){
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 80;  
    $(this).parent().parent().width(rand);
    $(this).parent().parent().height(rand);   
   fixImage($(this));
});

// Brings the photo dead center
function fixImage(obj){
        //alert("something changed");
        var pw = obj.parent().parent().width(); 
        var ph = obj.parent().parent().height();         
        var w = obj.width();
        var h = obj.height();
        console.log(w+"   "+pw);
        if(h>w){
            var top = (h-ph)/2;
            obj.css("top",top*-1);
        }else{
            var left = (w-pw)/2;
            obj.css("left",left*-1);            
        }

}
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/vL95x81o/4**

How can this be done without using jquery but only CSS? If the size of the div never changes, this solution is fine. But I'm looking into responsive designs and seems like the size of the `photo_container` div might need to change (via CSS) based on the size of the screen.

Here are the photos before being cropped:

> [image: Portrait Image] [image: Landscape Image]

Comment: Can you use a background image of a div rather than a img tag??

Comment: As I mentioned below, I rather not as it would mean some change in the code which is dependent on having <a> and <img>. Also not sure yet if this will affect SEO, how Googlebot picks up the images.

Comment: Some other good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830735/center-image-in-div-with-overflow-hidden/32191236#32191236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background solution that others have posted was my initial thought, but if you want to still use images then you could do the following:

**CSS:**

```
.photo_container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.photo_container img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/ECurtis.jpg/224px-ECurtis.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/220px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This will make any image inside to be either 100% high or 100% wide, depending on the shortest attribute, and centralise them horizontally and vertically.

*Edit*

It's worth noting that transform is not supported in IE8 or Opera Mini - http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Cool! This is close to what I wanted - no change in the current structure. But I'm seeing a gap of 1pix randomly appear between the image and the border on the left for portrait, and on the top for landscape. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I see what you mean actually, but only if the height or width of the `div` is an odd number - like 251px?   A little hack for this would be to set `min-width: 101%;` and `min-height: 101%;` so there is always a slight overlap, but I'll have a look later to see if I can find a way to stop this happening with 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works like a charm. Want to mention that even background image is not supported in IE8 and only partially in Opera Mini. So for those i'll resort back to jquery.

Comment: Great, I'm pleased it is suitable for you.  I haven't been able to look into this again yet but if I have any more information once I have I'll add it back here for you

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vL95x81o/5/

```
<!--p>Photo's height>width </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <div class="photo photo--1">
    </div>
</div>

<!--p>Photo's width>height </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <div class="photo photo--2">
    </div>
</div>

.photo_container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
}

.photo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.photo--1 {
    background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/ECurtis.jpg/224px-ECurtis.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.photo--2 {
      background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/220px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have changed the imgs to divs with background images and used background position cover with the image being centered.

Comment: Is it not possible without bringing in background image? Sort of don't want to change the current structure (including <a>) as I have some other JS dependent on it. Also will this have any affect on SEO? Like how the images are picked up by Googlebot..

Answer (score 0):

Use background images.

```css
.photo_container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
}
.photo_container a{
   
  /* Set the background size to cover to scale the image */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Position the image in the center */
  background-position: 50% 50%;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!--p>Photo's height>width </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#"  style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/ECurtis.jpg/224px-ECurtis.jpg);">
    </a>
</div>

<!--p>Photo's width>height </p-->
<div class="photo_container" >
    <a href="#" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/220px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg);">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this without using background-images or JS. The height comes from the before tag in the container. The 100% of the padding equals 100% of the widht. So the height has always the same width.

http://jsfiddle.net/a1rLeq06/

```
 <!--p>Photo's height>width </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="photo"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/ECurtis.jpg/224px-ECurtis.jpg" 
style="width:100%; height:auto;">
        </img>
    </a>
</div>

<!--p>Photo's width>height </p-->
<div class="photo_container">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="photo"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/220px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" 
style="width:auto; height:100%;left=-100px">
        </img>
    </a>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.photo_container {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.photo_container:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```