# CSS - hiding the overflow of an image isn't working

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with my website banner. When I view my banner image on a phone screen, the text on the banner is too small to see. Due to this, I made the width of my image 120% (on CSS) so the text would be larger on a phone screen. When I did this, [the banner just extended longer than the website length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nWnq.png) - but I want the excess banner to be cut off. I tried to solve this by using 'overflow: hidden' but it didn't work. Ultimately, I just want to crop the excess length off my banner but I don't know how.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="images/large_banner.png" width="1440" height="80" alt="Sister banner"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px){
    .banner{
            height: auto;
            width: 120%; 
            overflow: hidden;
           }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [center image in div with overflow hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830735/center-image-in-div-with-overflow-hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put width to the wrong place. You should paste height and width for image and put overflow: hidden; to div .banner.

Here's an example

```css
img{
  width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .content{
    width:360px;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  .banner{
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
    .banner img{
       width: 250%; 
       margin-left:-138px;
     }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="http://man-centr.uz/image/cache/catalog/slider/slider2-1920x641.jpg" alt="Sister banner"/>
        </div>
</div>
```